# 'Billing location for this contact' allowed on multiple addresses

Tags: addresses, location-type

Hoping someone can put me in the right direction for either an existing issue or help me understand the logic for the "Billing location for this contact" checkbox.

I am aware of related conversations around other location types/billing checkboxes related but cannot find one that matches the below:

At the moment you can select the "Billing location for this contact" checkbox on multiple (different) addresses.

On the latest Drupal demo (cid=187) site I could select

Address Location Type = Home - Ticked "Billing location for this contact"
Address Location Type = Billing - Ticked "Billing location for this contact"

The billing address is different from the 'home' one and in my mind I should only be able to tick the checkbox for 'billing' address once across all location types? (Maybe a warning at least to check which one should be the 'billing' one?).

It would be good to get some guidance if Civi will pull consistently just the location type for  invoices, labels, etc. OR if it will use the 'is_billing' field, how it will decide which one to use if there's two for the same contact set to '1' in the database.

Comment: You said you're aware of the other conversations but just checking have you seen  https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/1727 ? There's a push to remove the duplication/confusion.

Comment: I have. But I'm not convinced that would resolve the issue with being able to set 'is_billing' across multiple addresses

Comment: it could be worth you joining in that conversation though